# Can I remove a provisioning profile from Provisioning Portal?

Tags: app-store, provisioning, ios-provisioning

Can I safely remove a Distribution provisioning profile from the Apple Provisioning Portal without the app in the app store being affected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  Your Distribution certificate and provision profile are only used for submitting an app to Apple.  Once an app is approved and in the App store, you can download and unzip it, and note that Apple has (re)codesigned the app with Apple's own certificates.  However, if you let your iOS Developer enrollment expire, that can affect your app being in the App store.